# Best way to organize security group rules in AWS CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

For my example, I've got an EKS cluster, RDS database, and a VPN client endpoint, each with their own security groups that I want to explicitly define egress/ingress rules between.

I define the database security group in the RDS stack, import the EKS/VPN `aws_ec2.SecurityGroup`s, and then define an ingress rule:

```
database_security_group.add_ingress_rule(
    aws_ec2.Peer.security_group_id(eks_security_group.security_group_id),
    aws_ec2.Port.tcp(5432)
)
```

etc.  The problem with this is that if I make a change to the EKS stack that requires a replacement, it tries to delete the database stack.  I'm forced to comment out the ingress rule, deploy the database stack, deploy the EKS stack, un-comment the ingress rule, and deploy the database stack again.  This seems like an unnecessary sequence (not to mention it takes forever for these kinds of resources).  This applies to any of the stacks that own their own security group.

What is the best practice here?  How can I organize the security group rules so as to minimize the impact of one stack on another?

Comment: Did the answer help?

Comment: @gshpychka Not really.  It's not any different than what I wrote (manually writing out security group rules versus using some built-in property).  The question was about code architecture: where do I define security groups and rules between them in order to minimize pain when updates in one stack require a replacement?

Comment: It is actually different, because the security group rules are abstracted away. Check the second half of my answer, it talks specifically about stack dependency issues.

Comment: @gshpychka Boy, you are insistent.  I'm guessing you reported my comments and got them deleted, so I'll say again: the answer did not address the question.  In the two months since I asked the question, I have switched to Terraform because it works better.  You can stop coming back to this question now.

Comment: I did not, that must have been another mod. FYI I don't have the authority to "get them deleted", a mod must have looked at them and decided they go against the rules. I'll repeat what I said above: Check the second half of my answer, it talks specifically about stack dependency issues, addressing your question directly.

Answer (score 4):

The way to deal with security groups in CDK is not to deal with them at all.

CDK has the `ec2.Connections` class that all `IConnectable` constructs expose in the `connections` prop. The way you allow connections between constructs is with that class. Security groups under the hood is just an implementation detail.

From the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ec2.SecurityGroup.html):

> All Constructs that require Security Groups will create one for you if you don't specify one at construction. After construction, you can selectively allow connections to and between constructs via--for example-- the instance.connections object. Think of it as "allowing connections to your instance", rather than "adding ingress rules a security group". See the Allowing Connections section in the library documentation for examples.

> Direct manipulation of the Security Group through addIngressRule and addEgressRule is possible, but mutation through the .connections object is recommended. If you peer two constructs with security groups this way, appropriate rules will be created in both.

The way you would do this is pass the database construct (the entire thing) to the EKS stack as a prop.

Then you can set it up like this:

```python
eks_cluster.connections.allow_to_default_port(database)
```

And that's it.

Keep in mind that you have to do this in the correct stack to avoid a cyclic reference. From the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ec2-readme.html#cross-stack-connections):

> If you are attempting to add a connection from a peer in one stack to a peer in a different stack, sometimes it is necessary to ensure that you are making the connection in a specific stack in order to avoid a cyclic reference. If there are no other dependencies between stacks then it will not matter in which stack you make the connection, but if there are existing dependencies (i.e. stack1 already depends on stack2), then it is important to make the connection in the dependent stack (i.e. stack1).

> Whenever you make a connections function call, the ingress and egress security group rules will be added to the stack that the calling object exists in. So if you are doing something like peer1.connections.allowFrom(peer2), then the security group rules (both ingress and egress) will be created in peer1's Stack.

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ec2-readme.html#allowing-connections