# Add Resources to IngressRule as IPeer

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

```
const ecsAdminService = new ecs.FargateService(this, "AdminService", {
  cluster,
  taskDefinition:taskDefinitionAdmin,
  desiredCount: desiredCount,
  vpcSubnets: props!.vpc.selectSubnets({ subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC }),
  assignPublicIp: true, 
  securityGroups:[adminServiceSg],
  enableExecuteCommand:true,
  serviceName: serviceName
});

props!.dbSecurityGroup.addIngressRule(ecsAdminService, ec2.Port.tcp(3306),'allow mysql port');
```

I want to add the `fargate` to `addIngressRule` and `addIngressRule` required the `IPeer`

However I am not sure how to change the `fargate` to `IPeer`.

How can I make this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to this answer on the topic: [Best way to organize security group rules in AWS CDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72708289/best-way-to-organize-security-group-rules-in-aws-cdk/72826766#72826766)

The recommended way to do this is to use CDK's abstractions. It would look like this:

```typescript
ecsAdminService.connections.allowToDefaultPort(props.db);
```

You would need to pass the database instance/cluster in the props, not the security group. The required security group rules will be created automatically.

Comment: Ah I see. I think it is relevant with the basic structure philosophy of CDK. Thank you very much.