# Allow ingress from ECS service security group to RDS Security Group using AWS CDK

Tags: aws-cdk, aws-security-group

I am having ECS service & RDS PostgreSQL CDK .NET stacks.

I want to allow security group of ECS service on RDS database security group. So inbound traffic will only be allowed from that ECS task.
Right now, the rule is set to allow all traffic from anywhere.

`securityGroup.AddIngressRule(Peer.AnyIpv4(), Port.Tcp(5432));`

But this is not an ideal way to open the traffic from anywhere. I tried following but it is throwing an error:

`securityGroup.Connections.AllowFrom(EcsStackCDK.serviceContainerSecurityGroup.Connections, Port.Tcp(5432));`

Error: Unhandled exception. System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Any idea, what's wrong here? Or is there any better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

All of `FargateService`, `Ec2Service`, `DatabaseCluster` and `DatabaseInstance` constructs implement `IConnectable`, which means you don't have to deal with their security groups.

Basically, you shouldn't worry about security groups in your CDK code - they are an implementation detail and abstracted away.

By using the native `connections` props of these constructs, this would simply become (this is TypeScript, it would work the same in any CDK language):

```js
const myDb: DatabaseInstance;
const myService: FargateService;
myDb.allowDefaultPortFrom(myService);
```

Notice that I didn't have to specify the port either - CDK is smart enough to use the database's port automatically since it knows it.

Refer to this answer to a similar question: [Best way to organize security group rules in AWS CDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72708289/best-way-to-organize-security-group-rules-in-aws-cdk/72826766#72826766)